# AWS IoT, Persistant Sessions and the message ordering problem

Tags: mqtt, aws-iot

Apparantly AWS IoT doesn't guarantee the order in which messages on subscribed topics are received, however it also supports persistent sessions.
Do persistent sessions guarantee the ordering of messages in AWS IoT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer, persistent sessions doesn't guarantee the ordering of MQTT messages.

[Persistent Sessions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/mqtt.html#mqtt-persistent-sessions) store subscription information and pending Quality of Service (QoS) 1 messages should the devices become disconnected. When a device reconnects and resumes a Persistent Session, its subscriptions will be automatically reinstated and any stored messages will be delivered.